# Unable to access custom Locator in Protractor . Getting error as "Failed: by.shadowRoot is not a function"

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to access custom locator in my protractor suit as function .Followings it the locators details

```
"use strict";
  module.exports = function() {

By.addLocator('shadowRoot',function(selector, using) {
  var selectors = cssSelector.split('::sr');
   if (selectors.length === 0) {
    return [];
 }

 var shadowDomInUse = (document.head.createShadowRoot || 
 document.head.attachShadow);
  var getShadowRoot  = function (el) {
  return ((el && shadowDomInUse) ? el.shadowRoot : el);
 };
  var findAllMatches = function (selector /*string*/, targets /*array*/, 
   firstTry /*boolean*/) {
   var scope, i, matches = [];
    for (i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i) {
       scope = (firstTry) ? targets[i] : getShadowRoot(targets[i]);
       if (scope) {
          if (selector === '') {
              matches.push(scope);
          } else {
              Array.prototype.push.apply(matches, 
              scope.querySelectorAll(selector));
           }
       }
   }
  return matches;
 };   

  var matches = findAllMatches(selectors.shift().trim(), [using || 
   document], true);
   while (selectors.length > 0 && matches.length > 0) {
     matches = findAllMatches(selectors.shift().trim(), matches, false);
   }
   return matches;
  });
  };
```

When i am trying to access locator as

```
  element(by.shadowRoot('apps::sr nd-icon#icon')).click().then(function(){
   browser.sleep(10000);

    });
```

Getting following error

Failed: by.shadowRoot is not a function

Using gulp-angular-protractor with version 0.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 
`module.exports = (function() {...})`

Load the locator function in conf file 
`require('path/to/file')`